# Can the use of * to dump excess return in parallel assignment be made compatible in Python 2.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python 3.x allows dumping excess return in a parallel assignment with *

```
>>> a, b, *args = range(4)
>>> a
0
>>> b
1
>>> args
[2, 3]
```

But 2.x doesn't:

```
>>> a, b, *args = range(4)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a,b,*args = range(4)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there some future import that can make this statement compatible with Python 2.x?

Comment: Python doesn't refer to this as "parallel assignment." It's just called unpacking.

Comment: I picked the term from Ramalho's "Fluent Python" book

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK this feature is not available in Python 2, if you really need something like this – just write utility function

```
def unpack(iterable, elements_count):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    for _ in range(elements_count):
        yield next(iterator)
    # maybe use `list` or leave `iterator`-object
    yield tuple(iterator)
```

Then

```
a, b, args = unpack(range(4), 2)
```

will give an expected behaviour

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no equivalent unpacking support for Python 2 available.

In some cases, you can use slicing to approximate it for cross-compat code:

```
first, second, rest = val[0], val[1], val[2:]
```

Answer (score 3):

No. You can see the list of future statements Python 2.7 supports in the [`__future__` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html), and none of those future statements turn on support for this.

(Note that the `__future__` module isn't actually involved in the magic performed by future statements. It's mostly there for documentation purposes and to avoid confusing tools that expect all imports to correspond to a real module.)